# Error changing background image

Tags: jquery, html, image, background

I'm trying to change the background image of a different page through jQuery with an overlay, though, I'm doing something wrong. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
$("html").css({"background-image": "url("+../images/pattern copy.png+")", "url("+../images/visuals/visual3-edit.jpg+")", "center" "center" "fixed no-repeat;"});
```

I hope I'm using StackOverflow correct, it's the first time I'm attempting this.

Kind regards.

Comment: you may want `$("html").css({
    "background": "url(../images/pattern copy.png) center center fixed no-repeat"
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$("html").css({ "background": "url('../images/visuals/visual3-edit.jpg') center center fixed no-repeat" });
```

or if you are just changing the image...

```
$("html").css({ backgroundImage: "url('../images/visuals/visual3-edit.jpg')" });
```

Not sure what you mean by a different page.  Can you be more specific?

Also, try:

```
$("html").css({ "background-image": "url('../images/pattern%20copy.png'), url('../images/visuals/visual3-edit.jpg')", "background-position": "center", "background-repeat": "no-repeat", "background-attachment": "fixed"  });
```

Also, if you have a space in your filename, like this:  `pattern copy.png`, than the actual filename path will be:  `pattern%20copy.png`

Comment: Hey Solomon, thanks for your response. Basically the user opens a new page and I want to have a different background image. I'm using jQuery to change the CSS of the attribute HTML. Your provided code still gives a syntax error. I'm trying to figure what's wrong. The path to the image is correct.

Comment: well, the `../` code goes up a level, is that what you want?  If the images folder is relative to the html file, than you wouldn't use `../`

Comment: Yes, indeed, it should go up a level.